# What is the correct regression model to use?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

I have some data about some shipments. It includes the weight of shipment, origination destination, distance , airlines and a column with two values where it says if a shipment is late or not. I would like to see if I can predict for a given shipment with these parameters, will the shipment be late or not? I started building a glm(binomial) model for this but the results arent impressive, I am getting a 60 % match with all the factors that I considered.

So, the question is is glm(binomial) the correct regression model to use? or is there any other regression models that are better. Also, I have huge amount data- I tried building the model with only a hundred thousand rows.

EDIT: adding sample data

```
islate  weight  BC  origination_apc origination_country destination_APC destination_country Distance    Carrier
LATE    13  AKL AKL NEWZEALAND  BEG Serbia  1020    BP
LATE    28  AKL AKL NEWZEALAND  BEG Serbia  2500    SQ
LATE    36  NYC AKL NEWZEALAND  BOS USA 120 AU
LATE    22  NYC AKL NEWZEALAND  BOS USA 3522    SB
NOTLATE 34  AKL WLG NEWZEALAND  FRA GERMANY 5236    BP
NOTLATE 34.6    AKL WLG NEWZEALAND  FRA GERMANY 1452    TU
LATE    14  STO WLG NEWZEALAND  LBA UN KINGDOM  2145    TU
NOTLATE 13  STO TRG NEWZEALAND  LBA UN KINGDOM  2356    TU
LATE    3.9 LHR CHC NEWZEALAND  IND USA 4587    AC
LATE    3.9 LHR CHC NEWZEALAND  IND USA 4596    TU
```

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that. Please let me know what other information that you need and I'll do my best to provide that. Thank you :)

Comment: If the question is, what model to I use if my output variable is dichotomous (i.e. 0/1), then logistic regression is fine. However, it seems like you're asking for more advice from that.

Comment: I suggest that you dig into your data a bit more to find which variables are truly significant, and what patterns are present. You can't just throw data at multiple models hoping that one will give you what you want. This is how over-fitting happens.

Comment: In general your description of the problem suggests that the binomial model is appropiate in this context (being late is a yes/no event, right?). The fact that you get unimpressive results may be just due to the fact, that there are no substantive correlations in your data (statistics is not magic, it will not find something that is not there). But to say something more constructive you would have to provide more information. It would be nice to see some sample of the data you use and in general more information on variables you use.

Comment: Hi @sztal. I have added some sample data. I am considering the variables that are listed. These are the sample data on a shipment level. Here, I would like to predict if the shipment is late or not based on the other information. I am assuming the variables that I am considering are less in number and I should be considering more factors in?